# AS400 prog and dynamic classpath

Tags: java, classloader, ibm-midrange

i have to call an AS400 prog by a java class. i've found the method

```
ProgramCallDocument(connexion, "myProg");
```

it works fine, but "myProg" has to be a file into class path. But in my case this will be sent by a user through an html form.

So my question is: how can i load an xml file into the classpath dynamically ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's ok !

i've found out this method:

```
public ProgramCallDocument(AS400 sys,
                       String docName,
                       InputStream docStream,
                       ClassLoader loader,
                       InputStream xsdStream,
                       int type)
                throws PcmlException
```

which allow to create a DocumentCall based on the inputstream.

Answer (score 1):

If your XML file is in your classpath, then you can get an `InputStream` for it by using something like this:

```
public InputStream getInputStreamFromClasspathFile(String filename) {
    return this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
}
```

You should be able to parse your XML from the `InputStream`.

Comment: hi, in my example "myProg" is the xml file sent by the user... and this MUST be in the classpath, but is not, since it is sent by an html form and stored somewhere on the web server.

Comment: @kakashi99: well, if your HTML form stores it somewhere on the Web Server file system, I assume you know the path. In that case you can read it as a `File` directly from that path.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure this is what you're looking for ... but the ProgramCallDocument class let's you specify the class loader that's used to load the PCML document from.

See [ProgramCallDocument](http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/data/ProgramCallDocument.html#ProgramCallDocument%28com.ibm.as400.access.AS400,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29)

david

Comment: that's almost what i've found. but in thuis method the class loader will format the existing pcml doc, and not create a new one, so we still need a file on classpath. I've found what I need yesterday, but i was not able to answer my own question...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'format the existing pcml doc' ... the link I provided was to the ProgramCallDocument constructor that loads a pcml document using the specified class loader.